# About strpos in PHP

Tags: php, strpos

I searched the PHP documentation and didn't find an answer.

I am defining the following:

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],"course") == true) {
   echo "yes";
}else{
   echo "no";
}
```

That is, it will show **yes** if there is the word **course** in the URL, but I need an exception, for it to ignore for example when it has the exact word **my_course**.

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: `strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "course") && !strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "my_course")`

Comment: Remember that strpos can return a falsey result when it finds the string, so you should check for absolute false with `!== false`.

Comment: tip if this is for routing around your app you would be better off using `$route = explode('/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])` and checking with `if(isset($route[0]) && $route[0] === "course")`

Comment: To check for _"course"_ and not _"my_course"_, you'll need to use something like `preg_match()`

Comment: Maybe start with checking for "my_course", and only if it fails, check for "course".